# std::string_view constructor & validity outside the place it was defined

Tags: c++, c++17, string-view

Given the following code

```
std::string_view foo(){
    std::string_view sv("ABC");
    return sv;
}

int main(){
   std::string_view svv = foo();
}
```

1. Is it safe to say that since `"ABC"` is stored in the static area of the stack, `svv` is valid since the internal char array is still alive outside the scope of `foo`?
2. Is it true that it will be called the constructor (4) at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view/basic_string_view?
3. If it were = "ABC", does 1. still hold?

Comment: Your general concern about the `std::string_view` referring to a function local string is valid, though in this special case string literals have lifetime that exist longer than the scope of the function they were defined

Comment: Nitpick: There's no such thing as "the static area of the stack"; there's the stack, and there is global data storage. To your questions: 1) It's safe (see duplicate). 2) Yep (using a literal form like `auto sv = "ABC"sv` would be slightly more efficient by using form (3) with a compile time constant known length, rather than requiring it to determine length at runtime). 3) Yep, it's still the same initialization whether you do `std::string_view sv("ABC");` or `std::string_view sv = "ABC";`.